# Should I serialize keyPressed?

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, processing, keypress

I want to save some objects into a file. but I got `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

This is the full exception log:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: main
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at main$FileOperator.<init>(main.java:484)
    at main.keyPressed(main.java:79)
    at processing.core.PApplet.keyPressed(PApplet.java:3056)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleKeyEvent(PApplet.java:2931)
    at processing.core.PApplet.dequeueEvents(PApplet.java:2602)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2440)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1557)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:313)
```

And I think from `at main.keyPressed(main.java:79)` the problem is in main at row 79, so:

```
    void keyPressed() {  
if((key == 'F') || (key == 'f')){ 
      println("Save shapes into file");  // Save shapes into file
      value = 6;
      fileIo = new FileOperator(0,shapes);
  }
      if(key == CODED){
        //circle to ellipse
        if((keyCode == CONTROL) && (c.centerIsSet)){
          c.isItAnEllipse = false;
          c.setCircleRadius(sqrt((mouseX+c.x)^2+(mouseY+c.y)^2));
          shapes.add(c);
          c = new Circle();
          System.out.println("  Circle saved\n");
        }
        //Save a polygon if it is a polygon
         else if((keyCode == CONTROL) && (p.savable())){
          p = new Polygon();
          System.out.println("  Polygon finished\n");
        }
        //End a polygon if it isn't a polygon yet
        else if((keyCode == CONTROL) && (p.savable())){ //here is the row 79
          p = new Polygon();
          System.out.println("  Polygon cacelled\n");
        }
        //End a Catmull Rom
        else if(keyCode == CONTROL){
          cr = new CatmullRomManager();
          System.out.println("  CatmullRom spline saved\n");
        }
      }
    }
```

And I have some class, for example the `abstract class Shape implements Serializable` and `class Line extends Shape` and some others what extends `class Shape`.

I am trying to save the objects into file like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random; 

class FileOperator{
  FileOperator(int io, ArrayList<Shape> shapes){
    if(io == 0){
      try{
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        rand.nextInt(40);
        String filename = "draw" + rand + ".txt";
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
        for(Shape s:shapes){
          o.writeObject(s);
        }

        o.close();
        f.close();

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("ERROR: File not found"); 
      } catch (NotSerializableException e) {
          println("ERROR: trying to serialize: ");
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          println("ERROR: initializing stream");
          e.printStackTrace(); 
      }

    }else{
      //read
    }
  }
}
```

So I don't know but I am wondering whether I should serialize `keyPressed` somehow?

Or how can I resolve this exception?

Comment: Which line of code is line 79? What is line 484?  Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman as I wrote the 79 is: `else if((keyCode == CONTROL) && (p.savable())){ //here is the row 79` and I don't have row 484.

Comment: Personal opinion, but I would generally avoid object serialisation in most cases, and instead use either JSON parsing or XML parsing (JAXB) instead - it gives you control over HOW the parsing is done

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really make sense to serialize a function. You serialize **instances** of a class.

Your error is caused by trying to serialize an instance of a class that's not serializeable. It has nothing to do with a **function** not being serialized.

Trace through your code to find the class that's not serializeable, and then either mark it as serializeable or stop trying to serialize it.

It looks like your error is saying that the `main` class (side note: please follow standard naming conventions, classes should start with an upper-case letter) is not serializeable. Maybe you have an inner class or something?

Comment: @Gábor I'm not saying you can't use serialization. I'm saying you need to track down which part of what you're saving is not serializable. But there are a ton of ways to save data to file- JSON, XML, properties, your own custom format, etc. Start with something simple and get that working first. Get a simple serialization example working. Then if you have a question you can post a [mcve] along with a more specific technical question. Good luck.